# Reclassification of raster

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, reclassify

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm trying to create a script that will change classifications of a raster to:

0 for:  0,7-9,15-20,40,62-63,73,78-87,89-130,132-151,153-175,177-203,215,228,251-253

1 for:  all others

```
#RECLASSIFY LANDCOVER
#Considers 0 for:  63,81-83,87,111-112,121-124,141-143,190,195,     
#Considers 1 for:  All others.
#Considers "NODATA" for:  background, blank
import arcpy
from arcpy import env  
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = r'C:\Erosion\LandCover'
outReclass1 = Reclassify("CDL_2014.tif", "Value", 
                         RemapRange([[0,0,"NODATA"],[7,9,"NODATA"],[15,20,"NODATA"],[40,40,"NODATA"],
                                     [62,62,"NODATA"],[63,63,0],[73,73,"NODATA"],[78,80,"NODATA"],[81,83,0],
                                     [84,86,"NODATA"],[87,87,0],[89,91,"NODATA"],[93,110,"NODATA"],[111,112,0],
                                     [113,120,"NODATA"],[121,124,0],[125,130,"NODATA"],[132,140,"NODATA"],
                                     [141,143,0],[144,151,"NODATA"],[153,175,"NODATA"],[177,189,"NODATA"],
                                     [190,190,0],[191,194,"NODATA"],[195,195,0],[196,203,"NODATA"],
                                     [215,215,"NODATA"],[228,228,"NODATA"],[251,253,"NODATA"]]), 1)
outReclass1.save(r'C:\Erosion\Output\CDL_reclass.tif')
```

I was attempting to modify the script from the ArcGIS Resource Center Desktop Help.

Comment: Define better: is the listed method slow, does it not work, are the values wrong? You could also use Reclassify by Table: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sq000000, your values go into a table so you can reuse it.

Comment: @Michael Says invalid syntax on the last line.

Comment: An attractive alternative to consider is [InList](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/InList/009z000000m7000000/). The syntax is clearer and more congenial.  I haven't tested the performance relative to the other reclassification methods.

Comment: outReclass1.save(r'C:\output.gdb\RasterName'), you don't just need to tell it *where* you *must* also supply a dataset name. If you're saving to a folder location then you should include file extension, if you don't it will try to save as GRID which has severe limitations.

Comment: @Michael So, saving .tif files in a .gdb is bad?  I'm just getting started so perhaps I misunderstood what a .gdb is used for.

Comment: I'm just getting started so perhaps I misunderstood what a .gdb is used for.  Lastly, the original post has been modified to show what I'm working with now.  The Syntax problem has been solved.  Now, in yellow text, I get this message for two classification numbers: "The input raster minimum (1) & raster maximum (238) are out of range."
What does that mean?  I put select classifications as 0; including those with no data.  Do I need to specify No Data in the code, or can I simply add it to the other values I don't need as 0?

Comment: It's not *bad* you just can't save a file source (like tif, jpg, ecw, shp...) in a geodatabase. Everything that's stored in a geodatabase is a geodatabase type: Geodatabase Feature class, Geodatabase Raster... those types don't have extensions and you need ArcCatalog etc. just to see them.

Comment: @Michael  How do I avoid getting this error?  "The input raster minimum (1) and maximum (238) is out of range. To ensure a correct reclassification, edit ranges or use a different precision settings in the Reclassification dialog box."  Not sure what its expecting me to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should save the output raster to a raster format, not to a geodatabase, e.g.:

```
outReclass1.save(r"C:\output\reclass.tif")
```

***EDIT***: And there is a missing bracket in the Reclassify line (RemapRange is enclosed but not Reclassify). I've updated my code as well.

You can also simplify the `remap` parameter a little bit by using the `missing_values` parameter for all other values that must be remapped to 1:

```
outReclass1 = Reclassify("raster.tif", "Value", 
                         RemapRange([[0,0,0],[7,9,0],[15,20,0],
                                     [40,40,0],[62,63,0],[73,73,0],[78,87,0],
                                     [89,130,0],[132,151,0],[153,175,0],
                                     [177,203,0],[215,215,0],[228,228,0],[251,253,0]]), 1)
```

See the [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Reclassify/009z000000sr000000/) help page for more details and examples.

Comment: Still getting, "Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 10)" - which is for the outReclass1.save(r"C:\output\reclass.tif")

Comment: Running it in IDLE shows outReclass1 in red.  @GISGe

Comment: What do you mean? If you have a closing bracket missing, the error will show up farther in the code, where it is expected to be found (not where it is actually missing).

Comment: I got it working.  Thanks.  Only now it says, "The input raster minimum (1) is out of range.
To ensure a correct reclassification, edit ranges or use a different precision settings in the Reclassification dialog box.
The input raster maximum (238) is out of range.
To ensure a correct reclassification, edit ranges or use a different precision settings in the Reclassification dialog box."